# SpringBoot: Configurable @Qualifier to select bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, qualifiers

Small question for SpringBoot, and how to configure the bean using `@Qualifier` please.

I have a very straightforward piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.question</groupId>
    <artifactId>language</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <name>language</name>
    <description>Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
package com.question;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LanguageApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LanguageApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.question.service;

public interface LanguageService {

    String process(String name);

}
```

```
package com.question.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("french")
public class FrenchLanguageServiceImpl implements LanguageService {

    @Override
    public String process(String name) {
        return "Bonjour " + name;
    }

}
```

```
package com.question.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("english")
public class EnglishLanguageServiceImpl implements LanguageService {

    @Override
    public String process(String name) {
        return "Welcome " + name;
    }

}
```

```
package com.question.controller;

import com.question.service.LanguageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class LanguageController {

    private final LanguageService languageService;

    @Value("${configuration}")
    public String configuration;

    public LanguageController(@Qualifier(configuration) LanguageService languageService) {
        this.languageService = languageService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam String name) {
        return languageService.process(name);
    }

}
```

Expected:

What I hope to achieve is equally straightforward. I would like to pass some sort of configuration to `application.properties`, something like `configuration=french` or `configuration=english`.

At the controller layer, to use `(@Qualifier(configuration) LanguageService languageService)` And the correct concrete service will be used.

Actual:

Unfortunately,

`@Qualifier(configuration) + @Value("${configuration}") public String configuration;`

will yield `Attribute Value must be constant`.

Is there a way we can configure the concrete Bean via a configurable `@Qualifier` please?

I understand there is a way to workaround this by using ApplicationContext getBean.

But having this construct: @Qualifier(configuration) makes the code clean and easily understandable. How to achieve this please?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: The link you provided @Stultuske is pretty much my question. As you can see in the example of the tutorial ```@Qualifier("fooFormatter")``` the value is hard coded, not configurable. How to make it configurable please?

Comment: not. you don't. You provide two autowired beans, and based on (if value equals english -> use englishqualifiedBean else useOtherbean. basically: a factory pattern

Comment: This is again the point of my question, many thanks. I have some 100+ concrete language beans. And Autowiring hundreds of concrete beans, + a giant if statement on the bean name is not optimal. Is there a way to simply configure which bean to use at application start time with a configurable @Qualifier?

Comment: This might be against the "point" of your question, but at least it would work. You can't dynamically build a value you pass to an annotation. You might put them all in a Map, and have a specific (for instance that "english" and "french") mapped to them, and you can get them that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need 1 of the `LanguageService` beans active at a time, then you can use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on each of them, each using a unique `havingValue`. Like this (warning, untested code written from memory):

```java
interface ConfigKeys {
    public static final String LANGUAGE = "my.app.prefix.language";
}


@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ConfigKeys.LANGUAGE, havingValue = "english")
public class EnglishLanguageServiceImpl implements LanguageService {

    @Override
    public String process(String name) {
        return "Welcome " + name;
    }

}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ConfigKeys.LANGUAGE, havingValue = "french")
public class FrenchLanguageServiceImpl implements LanguageService {

    @Override
    public String process(String name) {
        return "Bonjour " + name;
    }

}
```

With that, you don't need any qualifiers, just set the `my.app.prefix.language` property in your config (application.properties or application.yaml) to the value you want, and there will just one `LanguageService` bean in the context. You can inject that bean wherever you need it without needing a qualifier.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Learned something new in the process. (It is ```name=ConfigKeys.LANGUAGE``` btw. Accepted and upvoted

Comment: Fixed that typo in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this dynamic, you'll need to use a workaround.
A factory pattern would do well, here. Instead of one bean, you would have two, and based on the value of that property, you would let your factory choose which one to use.

```
@Component
public class LanguageFactory {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("english")
  private LanguageService englishLanguage;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("french")
  private LanguageService frenchLanguage;

  @Value("${configuration}")
  private String chosenLanguage;

  public LanguageService getLanguageService() {
    switch(chosenLanguage) {
      case "english": return englishLanguage;
      case "french": return frenchLanguage;
      // add any other language you need
      default: throw new Exception("Invalid language: " + chosenLanguage);
    }
   }
}
```

So, in your LanguageController, you would get something like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private LanguageFactory languageFactory;

  @GetMapping("/test")
  public String test(@RequestParam String name) {
      return languageFactory.getLangaugeService().process(name);
  }
```

EDIT:

Another option would be to use a Map. You would avoid all the if-elses, but you would still have to add them to a Map.

```
@Component
public class LanguageFactory {

  private Map<String, LanguageService> languages = new HashMap<>();

  @Value("${configuration}")
  private String chosenLanguage;

  @Autowired
  public LanguageFactory(@Qualifier("english") LanguageService englishLanguage, @Qualifer("french") LanguageService frenchService) {
    this.languages.put("english", englishLanguage);
    this.languages.put("french", frenchLanguage);
  }

  public LanguageService getLanguageService() {
    LanguageService ls = this.languages.get(chosenLanguage);
    if ( ls == null ) {
      // handle the issue as you see fit
    }
    return ls;
  }
}
```

Comment: If we go that route, a simple ```applicationContext.getBean(configuration, LanguageService.class).process(name);``` can be much nicer. But that would require to pull the application context.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler option would be to group the related beans in `@Configuration` classes, and then use `@Conditional` to enable (or not) the configuration, and in turn, a set of beans. That way, you’re not dealing with individual beans, as you say you’ve many.

Comment: This is correct. Upvote. I accepted another answer because the example code is there as well, but this is definitely correct